# Azure - File Share using HTTPS

Tags: azure, https, file-sharing

Is it possible to share Azure Storage's files through HTTPS without using RestAPI? 
I know it's native feature is to provide this through SMB 3.0, but is there a way without having to develop something to create this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you mean is some kind of web interface to Azure Storage?

You could maybe leverage a tool like this:

https://github.com/sebagomez/azurestorageexplorer

You would need to host it in WebApp, but it might provide what you need? Or at least could be extended.

Alternatively the Azure Portal itself has a native web browser interface if it's just for a basic internal use case - i.e. you could grant your users the access they need to access there.

Comment: the only two ways to access a file share in a storage account is through the `RestAPI` or the `SMB` protocol. The storage explorer uses the Rest API. Same with the portal.

Comment: Exactly, hence why I am suggesting a 3rd party tool that has written a front-end to the REST API